# my chain as jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code:

```
<body>
    <div class="class0"> <a href="">link</a> </div>
    <div class="class0"></div>
    <div class="class0"></div>
</body>

<script>
    proto={};

    $ = function(selector){
        var tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        tags.__proto__ = proto;
        return tags;
    }

    proto.addClass = function(className){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            this[i].classList.add(className);
        }
        return this;
    }

    proto.html = function(){
        return this[0].innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

`console.log( $('div').addClass('class1').html() );` this works

`console.log( $('div').addClass('class1').html().addClass('class 2').html() );` but this not - need this to work

`html()`, on the one hand, should return `this[0].innerHTML`, on the other hand should return this.
I do not know how to combine it.

Comment: Why should `html()` return `this`?

Comment: As far as I know `__proto__` link is not supported in some browsers, In my opinion you should use `new` to link an object to another object as its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, a function can return only one value.

If you have a look at the jQuery fluent API also, the you can't do what you are trying to do with the [getter version of .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html)

---

The getter & setter version can go something like

```
proto.html = function (html) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
        return this[0].innerHTML;
    }
    this[0].innerHTML = html;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`html` should return `this` in case if it's a setter function (you don't have this yet):

```
$('div').addClass('class1').html('<span>HTML</span>').addClass('class 2');
```

In your case `html` is a getter function so it must return `HTML` string for the first element in collection. Hence there is no way you can combine both styles.

Comment: I use html() as a getter

Comment: Then it's not possible to make it chainable. You can only chain with setter version of `html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
proto.html = function(str){
    if(str == undefined){
        // getter mode
        return this[0].innerHTML;
    } else {
        // setter mode
        this[0].innrHTML = str;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$('div').html() // works as getter
$('div').html('some html').foo(); // works as setter
```

Answer (score 0):

The task hasn't decided yet.

The comment of author of the question (team leader at EPAM systems):

"Need to redefine this's toString inside methods. 
Now if you use the result as a string it will remain as string although you will 
return this"

The decision exists